# Cant figure out purpose of hyphen in actionscript

Tags: syntax, actionscript

I am new to coding in actionscript3. My question is what the hyphen do in this code?

```
tween = new Tween(menuScreen,"y",Strong.easeOut,menuScreen.y, -  /* <---- */
    menuScreen.height / 2,0.8,true);//Creates a tween animating the MenuView up
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [the unary `-` operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#subtraction).

> When used for negating, the operator reverses the sign of a numerical expression.

That is, the code provided is equivalent to the more common form:

```
tween = new Tween(menuScreen,"y",Strong.easeOut,menuScreen.y,
  -menuScreen.height / 2,0.8,true)
```

The placement of the newline is unfortunate (for readability), but does not affect the parsing.

Answer (score 2):

It does this:

`menuScreen.y, -menuScreen.height/2,0.8,true`

Basically makes `menuScreen.height` a negative number.
If `menuScreen.height = 200` then the equation will be `-200/2 = -100`